# Clojure, JavaScript (ECMA) and MCLR

Tags: javascript, clojure, clr

In his book: **Clojure for the Brave and True**, the author writes: *Clojure also targets JavaScript and Microsoft Common Language Runtime (CLR)*.

What does he mean with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is a backend for [Javascript (Clojurescript)](http://clojure.org/clojurescript) and for the [CLR (ClojureCLR)](http://clojure.org/clojureclr) in addition to the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that Clojure software can be compiled into JavasScript, like TypeScript into JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about CLR but for Clojure, I always took it to mean that people can now write Clojure code (via ClojureScript) and have it be used in the same environment that JavaScript can be used (i.e. on the browser).

Comment: What you are talking about could become a possibility when Google and Mozilla will launch their much discussed `WebAssembly` platform. Right now, the assumption is that WebAssembly will be like a sort of `JVM/CLR` style bytecode language, so other high level languages like ClosureScript can directly target that.